# How to specify default variables for imported Ansible Galaxy roles?

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

When writing a custom role for an Ansible playbook, it's possible to [specify defaults](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-default-variables). I would like to do the same when using a role from [Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/) (the Ansible “package manager”).

For example, when using the popular [redis role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/DavidWittman/redis/), I'd like to be able to specify a default `redis_version`, so that anyone importing that role will get the same.

Without centralizing this, I would put the redis version into the variable section in every playbook when using the role. That's not ideal. Other ways I can think of:

- Create a new role, put the default variable there, and then make the Galaxy-role a dependency. (Not sure if variables are passed down.)
- Put the default into `ansible.cfg[defaults]`.

What's the best-practice?

Answer (score 0):

> Figure out where to define a variable, and don’t make it complicated.   [Variable Precedence: Where Should I Put A Variable?](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

For example, [group_vars alongside the playbook](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html#group-and-host-variables). Or from dynamic inventory. Lots more places to put variables too.

If you want the user to only need to import a role, with no variables in their play or inventory, consider forking the role and changing the default.  You now have to maintain that, which is a disadvantage.  I would rather have my variables in a play, it is just a few lines.